# React, hide dropdown menu when input (text in input) change

Tags: reactjs

Need help. There is a dropdown menu that appears after entering text in the input field - searches for matches on request and displays found matches, or displays a message that no matches were found.

How to make it so that when the text in the input is changed, even by 1 character, the dropdown menu hides until the next output of the search result?

This is how it [work now](https://petrovskyi-yevhen.github.io/react_autocomplete/)

Here the code

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import cn from 'classnames';
import PeopleContext from '../contexts/PeopleContext';

export const People = React.memo(() => {
  const {
    input,
    setInput,
    applyQueryWithDebounce,
    filteredPeople,
    handleClick,
  } = useContext(PeopleContext);

  const handleInput = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const userInput = event.target.value;

    applyQueryWithDebounce(userInput);

    setInput(userInput);
  };

  return (
    <div className="dropdown is-active">
      <div className="dropdown-trigger">
        <input
          type="search"
          placeholder="Enter the name"
          className="input"
          value={input}
          onChange={handleInput}
        />
      </div>

      {input && (
        <div className="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <div className="dropdown-content">
            {filteredPeople.length > 0
              && filteredPeople.map((person) => (
                <button
                  key={person.slug}
                  type="button"
                  className="dropdown-item person-input-item"
                  onClick={() => {
                    handleClick(
                      `${person.name} (${person.born} - ${person.died})`,
                    );
                  }}
                >
                  <p
                    className={cn('has-text-link', {
                      'has-text-danger': person.sex === 'f',
                    })}
                  >
                    {person.name}
                  </p>
                </button>
              ))}

            {!filteredPeople.length && (
              <p className="dropdown-item has-text-danger">
                No matching suggestions
              </p>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
});
```

```
import React, {
  createContext,
  useState,
  useCallback,
  useMemo,
  ReactNode,
} from 'react';
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';
import { Person } from '../types/Person';
import { peopleFromServer } from '../data/people';

interface PeopleContextType {
  input: string;
  setInput: (query: string) => void;
  applyQueryWithDebounce: (query: string) => void;
  handleClick: (person: string) => void;
  filteredPeople: Person[];
  selectedPerson: string;
}

const PeopleContext = createContext<PeopleContextType>({} as PeopleContextType);

export const PeopleProvider: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState<Person[] | null>(peopleFromServer);
  const [input, setInput] = useState<string>('');
  const [selectedPerson, setSelectedPerson]
    = useState<string>('No selected person');
  const [appliedQuery, setAppliedQuery] = useState<string>('');

  const applyQueryWithDebounce = useCallback(
    debounce(setAppliedQuery, 1000), [],
  );

  const filteredPeople = useMemo(() => {
    return peopleFromServer.filter((person) => person.name
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(appliedQuery.toLowerCase()));
  }, [people, appliedQuery]);

  const handleClick = useCallback((person: string) => {
    setSelectedPerson(person);
    setPeople([]);
    setInput('');
  }, []);

  return (
    <PeopleContext.Provider
      value={{
        input,
        setInput,
        applyQueryWithDebounce,
        handleClick,
        filteredPeople,
        selectedPerson,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </PeopleContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default PeopleContext;
```

Thank you very much! I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

i would add a state value to your script `const[CharAddedOrRemoved, setCharAddedOrRemoved] = useState(false);` and in your `handleInput` function i would set the state`CharAddedOrRemoved` to `true` if a new character is written and `false` when a character is removed then i would change your div

```
<div className={CharAddedOrRemoved ? "dropdown is-active": "dropdown isnot-active"}></div>
```

then you could set the `dropdown isnot-active` to hidden in css, to hide the dropdown menu when a character is removed